# Way Of Converting a Matrix Into Echelon Form in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I know that I can use the `rref(A)` function to convert a matrix into the row reduced echelon form. But I am looking just for the normal echelon form (not reduced). And I couldn't find anything about it.

I thought a function like `ref(A)` may exist. But it doesn't.

Is there a way to do it in Matlab?

Comment: The "Gauss Elimination Method" half of the code on [this GitHub](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/esromneb/1d57b1d16d54cde37332/raw/386fc536b9c2bce6a7e481dc247917935af828e0/gauss.m) function appears to be what you need. There is also a [supporting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMApKEKisKE) by the user which might help you understand. I've not watched it so cannot vouch for it, but the code appears to work to create an upper triangular matrix, which is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2016 this doesn't exist out of the box in Matlab (see [ref](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/8480-row-echelon-matrix-form-not-reduced?)). You may have to do it manually. You could build a function that does a bunch of elementary row operations, ultimately you just need it to be an upper triangular matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
lu(A)
```

performs LU factorization of a matrix. So, you can get upper triangular matrix from there. Not sure though if it performs Gauss reduction

```
[L,U,P] = lu(A);
```

gives Lower Triangular Matrix `L`, Upper Triangular Matrix `U` and permutation matrix `P` such that `P*A=L*U`